# Why do I get IndexOutOfBoundsException after installing my app to another devices?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

Why do I get this error?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)                                                                                   
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.example.muhammad.exquizme.PlayQuizActivity.displayQuestion(PlayQuizActivity.java:109)
at com.example.muhammad.exquizme.PlayQuizActivity.onCreate(PlayQuizActivity.java:62)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

This error appeared already in my phone and it has been fixed already. Then I tried installing my app in my tablet device and  run it. When I pressed on a button to navigate to the PlayQuizActivity, it crashes and it says that it `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0`.

This is the code for **PlayQuizActivity.java**:

public class PlayQuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String QUESTION_MANAGER_URL = "http://mbcatubig.net16.net/ExQuiz%20Me/Quiz_Manager.php";
private int randomIndex, questionIndex = 1;
private SQLiteDatabaseHelper questionDatabase;
private RadioButton choiceBtnA, choiceBtnB, choiceBtnC, choiceBtnD;
private TextView questionTextView, qIndexView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_quiz);
    //questionDatabase = new SQLiteDatabaseHelper(this);

    qIndexView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentNumber);
    questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
    choiceBtnA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choiceA);
    choiceBtnB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choiceB);
    choiceBtnC = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choiceC);
    choiceBtnD = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choiceD);

    //Get Network State
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean isConnected = false;
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
            isConnected = true;
        }
    }

    if (isConnected) {
        getJSONFromURL();
        displayQuestion();
    } else {
        displayQuestion();
    }


    choiceBtnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswers(0);
        }
    });

    choiceBtnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswers(1);
        }
    });

    choiceBtnC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswers(2);
        }
    });

    choiceBtnD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswers(3);
        }
    });
}

private void displayQuestion() {

    qIndexView.setText("QUESTION " + questionIndex++ + " /10");
    randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(10);
    questionDatabase = new SQLiteDatabaseHelper(this);

    //Uncheck button
    choiceBtnA.setChecked(false);
    choiceBtnB.setChecked(false);
    choiceBtnC.setChecked(false);
    choiceBtnD.setChecked(false);
    if (questionIndex <= 10) {
        String question = questionDatabase.getQuestions().get(randomIndex).question; //this causes the error
        String[] choices = new String[4];
        choices[0] = questionDatabase.getQuestions().get(randomIndex).choices[0];
        choices[1] = questionDatabase.getQuestions().get(randomIndex).choices[1];
        choices[2] = questionDatabase.getQuestions().get(randomIndex).choices[2];
        choices[3] = questionDatabase.getQuestions().get(randomIndex).choices[3];
        questionTextView.setText(question);
        choiceBtnA.setText(choices[0]);
        choiceBtnB.setText(choices[1]);
        choiceBtnC.setText(choices[2]);
        choiceBtnD.setText(choices[3]);
    }
}

private void checkAnswers(int index) {
    String answer = questionDatabase.getQuestions().get(randomIndex).choices[index], correctAnswer = questionDatabase.getQuestions().get(randomIndex).answer;
    if (answer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
        Toast.makeText(PlayQuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                displayQuestion();
            }
        }, 2000);
        //Log.d("Is it correct?", "Correct");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(PlayQuizActivity.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                displayQuestion();
            }
        }, 2000);
        //Log.d("Is it correct?", "Incorrect");
    }
}

private void getJSONFromURL() {
    class QuestionExtractorTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(PlayQuizActivity.this, "Loading questions...", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            BufferedReader bufferedReader;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(QUESTION_MANAGER_URL);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }
                json = sb.toString().trim();

                return json;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonData) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonData);
            loading.dismiss();
            QuestionJSONParser questionJsonParser = new QuestionJSONParser();
            questionJsonParser.extractJSON(jsonData);
        }
    }
    QuestionExtractorTask questionExtractorTask = new QuestionExtractorTask();
    questionExtractorTask.execute();
}


class QuestionJSONParser {
    private static final String ROOT_OBJECT = "questions", QUESTION = "question", CHOICES = "choices", CATEGORY = "category";

    public void extractJSON(String jsonData) {
        try {
            //Get the questions object
            JSONObject questions = new JSONObject(jsonData).getJSONObject(ROOT_OBJECT);
            //Get the questions' objects
            Collections.shuffle(uniqueRandomNumber(questions.length()));
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
                String[] choices = new String[4];


                System.out.println(uniqueRandomNumber(questions.length()));

                JSONObject theQuestionObject = questions.getJSONObject(uniqueRandomNumber(questions.length()).get(counter) + "");
                String question = theQuestionObject.getString(QUESTION), category = theQuestionObject.getString(CATEGORY), correctAnswer = "";

                //Log.d("question", question);
                JSONArray theChoicesArray = theQuestionObject.getJSONArray(CHOICES);

                //Get choice object from the choices object
                for (int i = 0; i < theChoicesArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject choiceObject = theChoicesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    choices[i] = choiceObject.optString("choice");
                    if (choiceObject.getInt("is_correct_choice") == 1) {
                        correctAnswer = choices[i];
                    }
                }
                //add in SQLite Database
                questionDatabase = new SQLiteDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                questionDatabase.addQuestion(new QuizQuestion(question, choices, correctAnswer, category));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List uniqueRandomNumber(int length) {

        if (length != 0) {
            Integer[] arr = new Integer[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = i + 1;
            }
            return Arrays.asList(arr);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

I am trying to find out how to fixed this. I have thought about some possibilities thats causes the error. I guess when extracting json from an url and then parsing it, maybe it doesn't save those data to my sqlite database but this problem was fixed already so I have no idea how this is happening. It always say that the size is 0. Does this mean that I need to stick to my my phone. I think this is not about the sdk version, isn't it?

Here's my **SQLiteDatabaseHelper**.class:

class SQLiteDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String[] TABLES = new String[]{"question", "question_choices", "stats"};

public SQLiteDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "QUESTION_DATABASE", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //Create Questions Table
    String CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLES[0] + " (\n" +
            "  quiz_question_id INT  PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
            "  question TEXT ,\n" +
            "  choice_a TEXT,\n" +
            "  choice_b TEXT ,\n" +
            "  choice_c TEXT ,\n" +
            "  choice_d TEXT ,\n" +
            "  answer TEXT ,\n" +
            "   category TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLES[0]);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLES[2]);
}

//Managing question for the quiz
public void addQuestion(QuizQuestion questions) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //Insert in question table
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("question", questions.question);
    values.put("choice_a", questions.choices[0]);
    values.put("choice_b", questions.choices[1]);
    values.put("choice_c", questions.choices[2]);
    values.put("choice_d", questions.choices[3]);
    values.put("answer", questions.answer);
    values.put("category", questions.category);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLES[0], null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

//Managing best scores and best category for stats

public List<QuizQuestion> getQuestions() {
    List<QuizQuestion> quizQuestionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLES[0];
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (!cursor.isLast()) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            //Log.d("cursor.getString(1)", cursor.getString(1));
            String[] choices = {cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5)};
            quizQuestionArrayList.add(new QuizQuestion(cursor.getString(1), choices, cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7)));
        }
    }

    db.close();
    return quizQuestionArrayList;
}
```

}

The code above handles the sqlite database. What I'm basically trying to accomplish here if I'm connected to the internet, it will download the data to my sqlite database so when it's offline, it can be accessed. This happens already with my phone but with my tablet, it didn't work as it should as shown on the error above. Please if you need further details just let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0.`.  This says your array (questionDatabase?) is *EMPTY*!  That's the first thing to fix: why isn't it getting loaded?   ALSO: `randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(10) + 1`.  Q: is the array `1..n", or "`0..n-1`?  If the former; you're OK.  If the latter, you probably don't want "+1".

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes, it's empty but it doesn't happen with my phone somehow. About the `randomIndex` it has been modified, I was using that code before thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you have an empty database.  Your onCreate of your db helper creates a table, but it never adds anything into it.

Your network code is also incorrect- you call

```
    getJSONFromURL();
    displayQuestion();
```

But getJsonFromUrl launches an async task.  You don't want displayQuestion called until after the task is complete.  displayQuestion should only be called in onPostExecute, or if the data was downloaded in the past.

Comment: Yes that would work but when it's offline it will show null. That's why I did like that.

Comment: And it will never work.  You're executing an asynchronous network call.  You cannot use the results of that before the call is finished.  You can cache old results for offline mode, but the first time you have to wait for it to be done.

Comment: I think caching would be better for now so the application needs to be connected to the internet first then they can use it offline but anyways this is helpful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the code works on your phone but not your tablet,
the most reasonable one is not on the coding then.

Think about your db setup and connection rather than coding problems
Is that a local database? What 'local' means is that,is that a database only available on your phone? Did you really set up a database server for other devices to access, such as creating a TOMCAT / Wamp Server using local network.
(In this case,setting up the SQLite Server on PC and open it to your devices.)

Knowing where is the problem and know what you are doing is the most important as you already know that the code works on the phone but not tablet means there already problems at least happened to the db connection as the database return nothing after the access.

Comment: After doing a little research,i found that SQLite is a end-client db , which means that you have table data in your phone but not on your tablet, i guess

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually, I have a database in a web-server then I encode those data into json and did the server-side scripting for that so that I can extract it from my android app. Afterwards, I put that in my local database which is the SQLite database so it can be used when it's offline. it works already with my phone but not with my tablet. Does this mean that I have to remove some code then run it then put it back? We don't want to do that, do we?

Comment: End-client database? I'm not sure about what you said because it doesn't make sense as every android uses SQLite database as an alternative storage for data, am I right?

Comment: SQLite is just a database lives in application ( sorry i am a java developer but not android ), which means that the application serve as the client and the SQLite serve as database server.

You have to first store data from the client/get data from web to put inside the SQLite db first,otherwise it will be empty as no table is stored

Comment: If after the testing is alright please tick my answer, i really appreciating your help. If there exist any further problem, feel free to comment